# Get a column from results of EXEC that executes a dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

```
 
select 
       [OrderTypeName]
      ,EXEC('SELECT TOP 1 [Status] 
              FROM dbo.Order_' + t_ros. 
            [OrderTypeName]) as [Status]

FROM dbo.OrderTypes t_ros
```

Sample Data:

```
OrderTypeName
-------------
ABC
XYZ
...
```

Views: `dbo.Order_ABC, dbo.Order_XYZ....etc.`

I have many kinds of orders that are stored in different tables. These tables have different structure and I am trying to get common structure using views that has the same name as the type of Order. I know the above code is not the correct way and is also showing me errors because I can't use EXEC inside select. But I am unable to find the correct way to achieve this. Please help.

Comment: In truth, seems like you needs to fix your design

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results

Comment: @ThomA Trust me I really want to but the project I am working on in very huge project and these orders are created by previous multiple developers in last 10 years. I have very limited days to complete my task that's why I have no choice.

Comment: you can't use dynamic query in select,you must use case when (case when A=1 then select top 1 from order_1 ....)

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi then I need to make over 100 cases

Comment: Your sample data doesn't make any sense related to your question

Comment: first get list OrderTypeName then Generate Dynamic Query to All select OrderTypeNames with Order in a Dynamic Query

Comment: @DaleK I can't share the real data. But what I shared is enough to explain the problem. I just need a logic to get a column value from a dynamic query inside exisitng select statement. How that dynamic query is generated that I mentioned with that example and data.

Comment: i don't get it, can't you create a view that does: select 'ordertable1', status, orderid from table1 union all select 'ordertable2', SomeStatusColumn, orderId from table2 union all select 'ordertable3', AnotherStatusColumn, SomeColumnThatContainsOrderId3 from table3

Comment: A `VIEW`, like @siggemannen mentions, would be the "quick and dirty" solution, however, it won't scale. If your bad designers decide to add more tables, then those tables won't appear in the `VIEW`'s definition. So a "quick and dirty" solution might be the "answer" for this week, but for next month, fixing the design should be your goal

Comment: To execute this type of SQL, build the whole SQL as string thus enable dynamic SQL. Then execute the whole string. Performance will be bad due to existing design and the required iteration for each ORDER_... table.

Comment: You can generate and run a whole query from this query, but friends said that the method you used is not correct. .declare @sql varchar(max)=''
select @sql= STRING_AGG('
select [OrderTypeName],(SELECT TOP 1 [Status] 
from dbo.Order_'+ OrderTypeName +') as [Status] 
FROM dbo.OrderTypes where OrderTypeName=''' +OrderTypeName +'''',' union ') from OrderTypes

exec( @sql)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the whole thing into dynamic SQL, you cannot execute dynamic SQL in the middle of a query.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG('
SELECT
  ' + QUOTENAME(OrderTypeName, '''') + ' AS OrderTypeName,
  (SELECT TOP (1) Status
   FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME('Order_' + ot.OrderTypeName) + '
  ) AS Status
',' UNION ALL ')
FROM OrderTypes ot
JOIN sys.tables t ON t.name = 'Order_' + ot.OrderTypeName
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE s.name = 'dbo';

PRINT @sql;   -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note the use of `QUOTENAME` to correctly escape names.

You can use `sp_executesql` to pass parameters to the dynamic query.

Comment: I need some time to try it and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @abolfazl-sadeghi as this is basically just a fixed up version of what he suggested - instead of trying to use EXEC inside the query, instead build a union query dynamically then EXEC once.

As already discussed, this is obviously not an ideal way to be doing things, but I appreciate you are constrained by the existing design.

To improve the resilience of this going forward, I have also added a join to the system schema to verify that the views actually exist and have a [Status] column. That way if someone drops a view, or adds a bad entry to the ordertypes table, it will still work. It wont currently handle the case where you have a variety of column types for [Status] - you could work around that by converting to varchar in the "TOP 1" query - but obviously then the output would be a varchar, and that might not be what you want. You could also constrain to a column type.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(' select ''' + [OrderTypeName] + ''',(SELECT TOP 1 [Status] from dbo.Order_' + [OrderTypeName] + ') as [Status]', ' union ')
FROM dbo.orderTypes ot
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
    ON c.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND c.TABLE_NAME = 'Order_' + [ot].[OrderTypeName]
    AND c.COLUMN_NAME = 'Status';
EXEC (@sql);
```

Comment: I need some time to try it and let you know.

Comment: You are missing `QUOTENAME` to correctly quote column names and values, also `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is for compatibility only, you should just use `sys.tables`